# git: can you associate files with a branch without committing them?

Tags: git

I have some unstaged files that I want to use with features in one branch (it's testing data) and when I switch branch I would like these files to go away (stay with the branch) and come back when I switch back to it.
I know I could git stash the files and then git pop them when I switch back - but then I need to keep this in mind myself - I'd like to have it automatically happen.
I don't want to commit the files though as they should not end up in the commit i gonna push.

Can this be done? if so, how?

Comment: Why not having those files out of the repo? Furthermore, since you don't want to track them, I don't see why you want them to _go away_. They can just be sitting there, no?

Comment: @Enrico because it's usually temporary test files - but they are associated with that version of the branch. they are BIG (and thus I don't want them in the repo), they are not production ready, but they are branch specific

Comment: Files aren't *associated with branches*, in any meaningful sense. Files exist in *commits*, in Git. You tell Git: *get me commit number _____* (fill in the blank), and then those are the files that appear in your work-tree: the files that are in that commit. A branch name just holds one commit hash ID, i.e., one commit number.

Comment: For what you are doing, consider using `git worktree add` instead. You can make a temporary work-tree, do stuff with it, then destroy it whenever you like. Each work-tree has a specific commit, perhaps due to having that specific branch name as its current branch.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using  `.gitignore` in combination with a post-checkout git hook.

This way you can be sure the changes will be ignored but can also trigger a file copy or delete when using `git checkout`

https://schacon.github.io/git/githooks.html